# Linq Select Max Value Dataset

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 table connected with primary and foreign concept.

model -> studentRecord

```
public class studentRecord
{
    public string studentName{ get; set; }
    public int year{ get; set; }
}
```

Table 1 -> student

```
studentId  studentName
----------------------
 1             Sam
 2             Mani
 3             rajah
```

Table 2 -> subject

```
subjectid    subjectName
------------------------
  1            english
  2             maths
  3            physics
```

table 3 -> register

```
 registerId   studentId   subjectid    Year
--------------------------------------------
     1           1              1       1
     2           1              2       1
     3           1              3       1
     4           1              1       2
     5           1              2       2
     6           1              3       2
```

i want to get the record of the second year of the student.
my linq code

```
var op = (from student in db.student.where(x => x.studentId == 1)
          join register in db.register
          on student.studentId equals register.studentId
          select new studentRecord{studentName = student.studentName, year = register.Year}).ToList<studentRecord>().Max(x => x.Year)
```

I am getting error. Is there any appoach with good performance. Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the error message as well. Helps finding the exact cause.

Comment: like max cannot applied

Comment: Before calling Max, convert the LINQ result to List then call Max over it (i.e. (...).ToList().Max().)

Comment: Still I recommend please put the entire exception message in your question. That will help you get more precise answers. And also mention if you are using Entity Framework or not (`db` seems to be a `DbContext`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tested the query in Linqpad and the following query works just fine for me.

```
void Main()
{
    var op = (from student in Students.Where(x => x.StudentId == 1)
              join register in Registers
              on student.StudentId equals register.StudentId
              select new {student = student.StudentName, Year = register.Year})
    .Max(x => x.Year);

    op.Dump();
}
```

And profiler shows the following SQL.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT MAX([t1].[Year]) AS [value]
FROM [student] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [register] AS [t1] ON [t0].[studentId] = [t1].[studentId]
WHERE [t0].[studentId] = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=1
```

---

Anyway what you *probably* want is this:

```
from student in Students.Where(s => s.StudentId == 1)
join register in Registers.Where(r => r.Year == Registers.Max(x => x.Year))
on student.StudentId equals register.StudentId
select new studentRecord
    {
        studentName = student.StudentName, 
        year = register.Year
    })
.ToList<studentRecord>();
```

*`Students` is in your code `db.student` etc.*